# Flutter & Firestore async return to factory

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble with a factory function in my project.
The case is that I have a class that looks like this (cut down some code but so you understand the idea):

```
class Recipe {
  final String? name;
  final List<Ingredient>? ingredients;
}
```

And another class that looks like this:

```
class Ingredient {
  final String? name;
  final int? kcal;
  final int? carb;
  final int? fat;
  final int? protein;
  final String? unit;
}
```

In Cloud Firestore I have then the database setup like this:

```
Database/
recipes/
    recipe1/
        String: name
        List: ingredients/
            Map/
                String/ ingredient1
                String: unit
            Map/
                String/ ingredient2
                String: unit

    recipe2/
        String: name
        List: ingredients/
            Map/
                String/ ingredient1
                String: unit
ingredients/
    ingredient1/
        String:name
        number: kcal

    ingredient2/
        String:name
        number: kcal
```

So what I want to do is create a function that fetches the recipe from Firestore which means it also needs to fetch the ingredients. My problem has come from the fact that I can't use an async function in the factory Recipe.fromFirestore() function that I'm trying to write.

Curren't functions I'm trying to get to work:

```
  factory Recipe.fromFirestore(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
    SnapshotOptions? options,
      ) {
    final data = snapshot.data();
    // Check if the data is available and has the expected structure
    if (data == null ||
        !data.containsKey('name') ||
        !data.containsKey('ingredients')) {
      print('Invalid data structure or missing keys');
      return Recipe();
    }

    final List<dynamic>? ingredientsData = data['ingredients'];

    //Create a list of the ingredients
    List<String> ingredientNames = [];
    for (var ingredient in ingredientsData!) {
      ingredientNames.add(ingredient['ingredient']);
    }
    print(ingredientNames);
    //Use list to create and return an array of the ingredient objects
    List<Ingredient>? ingredients =
        getIngredients(ingredientNames) as List<Ingredient>?;

    return Recipe(
      name: data['name'],
      ingredients: ingredients,
    );
  }

getIngredients()

  static Future<List<Ingredient>?> getIngredients(List ingredientNames) async {
    print("1");
    List<Ingredient?> ingredientList = [];
    print("2");
    for (var ingredientName in ingredientNames) {
      print("3");
      Ingredient? ingredient =
          await DatabaseService().getIngredient(ingredientName);
      print("4");
      ingredientList.add(ingredient);
      print("5");
    }

    return ingredientList;
  }
```

DatabaseService().getIngredient()

```
  Future<Ingredient?> getIngredient(String name) async {
    print("1 1");
    final ref = _db.collection("ingredients").doc(name).withConverter(
          fromFirestore: Ingredient.fromFirestore,
          toFirestore: (Ingredient ingredient, _) => ingredient.toFirestore(),
        );
    print("1 2");
    final docSnap = await ref.get();
    print("1 3");
    final ingredient = docSnap.data(); // Convert to Ingredient object
    print("1 4");
    if (ingredient != null) {
      print("1 5");
      return ingredient;
    } else {
      print("No such document.");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And my factory Ingredient.fromFirestore() - No issues here but just so you have all the funcitonality

```
  factory Ingredient.fromFirestore(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
    SnapshotOptions? options,
  ) {
    final data = snapshot.data();
    return Ingredient(
      name: data?['name'],
      kcal: data?['kcal'],
      carb: data?['carb'],
      fat: data?['fat'],
      protein: data?['protein'],
      unit: data?['unit'],
    );
  }
```

How I have been approaching this problem has been to return a list of Ingredients in to the recipe factory and then create the objects but I'm starting to wonder if that is the correct approach. Since I can't use async functions I don't know how I'm supposed to solve the problem which makes me believe I'm attacking the problem in the wrong way. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a `static` method that is `async` instead of a `factory` constructor.

Comment: Ok how? I have no idea where I should do that, and what method I should change

Comment: Remove your `factory` constructor that needs to call asynchronous functions. Replace it with a `static` method.